# My computer does not detect android phones on MTP

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, mtp

I was able to connect android phones as a MTP device a few weeks ago. Then, I started to use my xperia z3c as an emulator in Android studio. Now i cant reach my folders on computer by connecting with MTP. My OS is Windows 8.1 .
I tried many ways to solve it, uninstall the drivers etc. but i couldn't solve. I tried to connect with USB debugging but again no connection. I can use my device in android studio as an emulator, when i connect my phone with USB cable i can hear the sound that approves that phone is connected also i can see my device on device manager under the title of unknown devices and its name is D8503(Sony's offical name) Unfortunately i couldn't any android phone via MTP connection. When i tried on another pc, it works well.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the notification bar and collapse. There should be a notification which tells you about the connection type. Maybe your device is connected as a camera. Change this.

Comment: There are only two notifications in navigation bar. One is connected to Pc in MTP mode. Other one is USB debugging connected.

Comment: `I can use my device in android studio as an emulator` This is **not** a good idea. You should develop on emulators and only **at the end** test on real devices. `When i tried on another pc, it works well.` Then, there's no communication between the device and the other PC. It may be a driver problem (I wouldn't be much surprised).

Comment: What do you mean by there's no communication between the device and the other PC? How can they be connected without communication? Also i couldn't see my device on pc companion( Sony's official connection program)

Comment: They are **physically** connected by a cable. But they don't communicate (they **don't talk** to each other).